# Motorcycle not starting unless I force it into first gear, but the battery itself is ok

Tags: engine, motorcycle, kawasaki

I am having a weird issue with my Kawasaki Z650 2019, as per title. It used to start when I just pulled the clutch, now it needs be forced into first gear in order for it to start (while holding down the start button).

The bike has ~7500 km, and I brought it to the dealer a couple of weeks ago to get it checked. They said the battery was fine, it had like 96% charge and they charged it back up and they had no clue where the problem might come from (they said it might be that the battery is actually at fault but their tools cannot detect it - but it's highly unlikely and thus I wanted a second opinion).

This video shows what the bike does (it is from around a month ago, when it still started by just pulling the clutch):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWl4axrNBvQ (issue at 0:15).

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not sure I understand your problem, what do you mean 'forced into gear'? If sounds like you were having starting issues  for awhile and that the gear thing is recent, what was happening before that?

Comment: Hi @GdD, sorry if I did not explain myself clearly, I'll try again! Basically the problem is that, in neutral, the bike does not start; rather, it does that sound you can hear at 0:15 in the video. When I shot the video, as you can see from it as well, the bike starts when I pull the clutch, even if not in first gear. Now though, the bike will keep doing the weird noise even with the clutch pulled, and will actually start only if I press the start button while shifting into first gear. I hope it's clearer now!

Comment: So the act of changing gears makes the starter engage?

Comment: I have no idea @GdD, unfortunately I do not know mechanics this well :P at the dealer they told me that the fact it would start with the clutch pulled could have something to do with the flywheel - but I have no idea how this relates to the issue now (not starting unless I shift into first). But yeah, it would appear to be the case for the issue at hand.

Comment: The video also shows the bike starting *without* the clutch (at 0:11).

Comment: Yes @WeatherVane, it did indeed, but it stopped doing that now :(

Comment: Suspect the neutral detector. Previously (in the video) the lockout system sometimes thought the gear was engaged, when in neutral. Now it is worse, it thinks it is in neutral when engaged. If the engine sounds as though it is trying to start, that might be due to an intermittent connection.

Comment: @WeatherVane not sure about this, but shouldn't it not show the N on the display if the detector wasn't working? Because the N is there when it's in neutral (and neutral works correctly even while riding)

Comment: I'd suggest the neutral detector as well. There may be a separate thing which shows the "N" indicator and the other which detects neutral.

Comment: Assuming it was, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, how does it fit with the fact that the bike won't start in neutral even if the clutch is pulled? And is there anything I can do to further confirm this / solve the issue?

Comment: This would mean, regardless of the light showing "N" on the dash of the bike, if the bike isn't being detected to be in neutral, it won't want to start. By moving the gears through from neutral to 1st, the bike may be "seeing" it as being in neutral and allowing it to start. I'm spitballing here, trying to make the circumstances fit ... it seems logical, but I may be way out in left field. Something more to talk to your bike shop about.

Comment: The starter lockout considers three things: gear, clutch and kickstand, so the fault might not be reflected in the 'neutral' indicator lamp.

Comment: Ok but shouldn't it just "lock" the starter from starting the engine? My question is, why does it do that weird "tac tac" noise when pressing the start button? When, for example, the kickstand is down, it just doesn't do anything... @WeatherVane

Comment: It is not supposed to do anything with the kickstand down. If there is an intermittent connection from the gear detector which is affected by vibration and motion of the parts, that might explain it. There might be a loose connection somewhere.